# PHP Excel save only one sheet as pdf

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

i'm using phpoffice/phpexcel an have a problem.

1. I have a excel file with 9 sheets
2. I open 6 of this 9 sheets ($objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly([...])) do set some values and calculate
3. I save this new excel file with 6 sheets

Info: one of the 6 steets is a overview site which have some references to the other sheets

I there any method to save only the overview sheet as PDF?

My Lines:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

if (!file_exists("orginal.xls")) {
    exit("Please create orginal.xls first." . EOL);
}

PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod(PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_in_memory);

echo date('H:i:s') , " Load from Excel2007 file" , EOL;

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');

$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(array("Dateneingabe", "Leistungen EK", "Flugliste", "Sprachen", "Buchungsübersicht", "Verkaufspreise", "Offerte", "Transferdauer"));

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("orginal.xls");

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName('Dateneingabe');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D102', '220');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F102', '220');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
//$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
$objWriter->setOffice2003Compatibility(true);
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xls', __FILE__));

 //SAVE AS PDF

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');

$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(array("Dateneingabe", "Leistungen EK", "Flugliste", "Sprachen", "Buchungsübersicht", "Verkaufspreise", "Offerte", "Transferdauer"));

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("index.xls");

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName('Offerte');

$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;

$rendererLibrary = dirname(__FILE__).'/dompdf/dompdf/';

PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName, $rendererLibrary);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');

$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);

$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.pdf', __FILE__));
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Like my lines, i only can save the full excel file with all steets.

Comment: If i only load the overview sheet `Offerte`, the references got lost

Answer (score 0):

By default, the HTML and PDF Writers (the PDF Writer uses output from the HTML Writer that it converts to PDF using any of the supported PDF Writer libraries) will only create a single sheet output.

However, these Writers allow you to select which sheet to write using the `setSheetIndex()` method, so you could write out files for each individual worksheet in turn, and then "stitch" them all together using any of the PDF stitching tools that exist... or there is also a `writeAllSheets()` method.

Answer (score 0):

use mpdf tool like below code

use mpdf tool to convert your data into pdf formate .